# How to make tab key to delete inserted text in entry when it passes to next entry window tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When I press tab key and when the cursor changes the entry it shoud instatntly delete text inside but in my case it matches text and than deleted. How to delete inserted text when the cursor changes entry like in the  insted of matching it ?
First effect:

[image]

The code

```
def func(event):
    e2.delete(0, "end")
                         #e2 - entry password

e2.bind("<Tab>",func)
```

Comment: Is the image showing the result of shifting focus from `username` entry to `password` entry by pressing `tab` key?  If yes, then it is normal result based on your posted code.  What do you want exactly in this case?

Comment: yes and when I press tab once again it deletes text but I need wen it shift once it deletes instantly

Comment: Then you should bind on `<FocusIn>` instead of `<Tab>`.

Comment: `e2.bind('<FocusIn>',lambda event: e2.delete(0,END)) ` Does this work?

Comment: Yes it also works!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple entries and you press `Tab` you move on from widget to another and `e1` is losing focus and `e2` is gaining focus, so why don't you try:

```
e2.bind('<FocusIn>',lambda event: event.widget.delete(0,END))
```

Or if you want to use your `func()` then say:

```
def func(event):
    event.widget.delete(0,END)
e2.bind('<FocusIn>',func)
```

You could also do the vice-versa too

Do let me know if any errors or doubts

Cheers

Comment: Better use `event.widget.delete(0, END)` instead of `e2.delete(0, END)`, then `func()` can be bind on different entry boxes.